# What is the proper way to have additional content when changing state

Tags: java, state-pattern

I have a class like this :

```
public class Machine {
    enum State {
        STARTED, STOPPED
    }

    private State state;
    private String whyIsItStopped; // only used in STOPPED state

    ...
}
```

I wonder what is the proper way to do this. I have a way more complexe class with this and it seem to be a mess if I do this.

The problem comes for my architecture, can you give me some advices  ?

**UPDATE**

Using the State Pattern I arrive with a nearly solution like :

```
public interface State {

    public String whyIsItStopped();

    public class Started implements State {
        @Override
        public String whyIsItStopped() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Stopped implements State {
        private final String reason;

        public Stopped(String reason) {
            this.reason = reason;
        }

        @Override
        public String whyIsItStopped() {
            return reason;
        }
    }
}

public class Machine {

    private State state = new State.Started();

    public String whyIsItStopped(){
        state.whyIsItStopped();
    }

    // setState etc ...
}
```

State pattern seems good to change behaviour of a same method, but it is  strange for additionnal field / data.

The problem is that it's not really the same object and polymorphism cannot be really useful.
I have to test if the Machine is Stopped before getting its content (as the manner of an instanceof)

```
if (machine.isStopped()){
     println(machine.whyIsItStopped());
}
```

Another way may be to set the getter only on the Stopped state

```
public interface State {

    public class Started implements State {}

    public class Stopped implements State {
        private final String reason;

        public String whyIsItStopped() {
            return reason;
        }
    }
}
```

And to retrieve the message :

```
if (machine.isStopped()){
    println(((State.Stopped)machine.getState()).whyIsItStopped());
}
// Yeah that's not really beautiful
```

Either it's strange in architrecture or in the utilisation.

Do you have any other solution, better than an instanceof ?

Comment: The answer by Andres is spot on. You implement a **state machine** using polymorphism - an (abstract) base; and state-specific subclasses. You do **not** "hardcode" your fsm manually this way.

Comment: Use the handle method described in the pattern instead of a particular method on each class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems an obvious case for the [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). It will allow you to implement a solution that can be extended with new states without modifying the already existing code.

> The state pattern is a behavioral software design pattern that
>   implements a state machine in an object-oriented way. With the state
>   pattern, a state machine is implemented by implementing each
>   individual state as a derived class of the state pattern interface,
>   and implementing state transitions by invoking methods defined by the
>   pattern's superclass.